# SQL Server equivalent of MySQL Load xml infile

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have been using the `MySQL` Load `XML` Infile to load an xml file into a `MySQL` tables. The xml file has this format

```
<Detail_Collection>
    <Detail
        JobId=“12345”
        JobDescription=“Job1”
        Sold_To=“Customer1”
    />
    <Detail
        JobId=“23445”
        JobDescription=“Job2”
        Sold_To=“Customer2”
    />
</Detail_Collection>
```

My table looks like this

```
JobId   
JobDescription   
Sold_to
```

Every thing works fine.
I am finding myself having to move from MySQL to SQL Server and can't seem to find a simple way to do this in SQL Server. Am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a SQL query to fetch the job data from your XML file into SQL Server database table, please check the below T-SQL syntax for querying XML data on SQL Server

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml = '
<Detail_Collection>
    <Detail
        JobId="12345"
        JobDescription="Job1"
        Sold_To="Customer1"
    />
    <Detail
        JobId="23445"
        JobDescription="Job2"
        Sold_To="Customer2"
    />
</Detail_Collection>'
select @xml

select
 job.value('@JobId','int') JobId,
 job.value('@JobDescription','varchar(400)') JobDescription,
 job.value('@Sold_To','varchar(400)') Sold_To
from @xml.nodes('/Detail_Collection/Detail') as jobs(job)
```

You can find tutorials on [querying XML on SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/query-xml-using-sql-xml-in-sql-server.aspx) at given reference